# bandwidth overheads for mail with ssl

Tags: email, encryption, ssl

I have been reading that the overheads of encryption in HTTP protocol is negligible. Is the same true for SMTP too ?

If I send a mail encrypted will the bandwidth consumption be any significantly larger ?

Comment: Do you use SSL-encryption below the SMTP level, or do you send an encrypted message (S/MIME or PGP) over SMTP, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a research project on this a few years ago. 1700 data points changing every parameter we could think of, including SSL vs plaintext. We discovered, rather to my surprise, that over practical Internet links SSL was 33% as fast as plaintext. I expected it to me much slower.

Comment: 33% seems to be slower than I would expect actually. Were there many handshakes in this?

Comment: There were handshakes in the middle of the transfers at random intervals, not all that many in total.

Comment: I believe the OP is interested in space overhead more than speed (he asked about bandwidth consumption).

Comment: Greg has that right. Will I be consuming any more bandwidth. 
A Banking client of ours is emailing transaction notes and he already has been having his bandwidth choked ( sending close to a million mails of 400kb each to a relay server at the ISP ). Now they have to implement TLS so that their mails reach the IDC encrypted. Will they consume any extra bandwidth

Comment: @Ram As long as there is a BufferedOutputStream around the SSL socket's output stream the bandwidth difference isn't significant. In the worst case of writing an unbuffered byte at a time directly to an SSL socket output stream the bandwidth requirement can go up by a factor of over 40, because of using an entire SSL record for every byte, but that is a pathological case.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many dependencies and variables, key size, chain lenght, used protocol, session key (re-)negotiation, timing issues etc. etc. etc. It is probably best to test this with a good packet analyzer like Wireshark. I would not say the overhead is neglectible, especially not if you send many small messages. In that case you might consider creating a tunnel instead, to avoid initial overhead. Key renegotiation will then play a part as well.

To minimize SSL trafic you might also look into ECC, using stream ciphers, single certificate chains etc. etc. but I would advise you only to go that direction if *absolutely* necessary, as it *will* be a more complex and dangerous route.

[EDIT] If you send large messages of 400K each then I would think that overhead is not that large. The ciphertext size won't be too much different from the plain text size, so overhead is minimalized.

Comment: Oh, you might want to find [this article](http://www.belshe.com/2010/11/18/ssl-compression-and-you/) of interest, it talks about SSL level encryption - and most MIME data is highly compressible base 64 :)

Comment: I meant SSL level **compression** of course, not **encryption**.